How does my recursive function in C work?
I wrote a recursive function in C to free memory allocations made by a program that generates a tree of nodes. However, I can't work out how it works - but it does pass the check50. Perhaps I've not written it well enough for me to understand it.
I've tried following the debugger but I just cannot get my head around how it manages to traverse 3 generations of parents successfully.
I suppose my main questions are:

How does this function free from bottom to top of the ancestry tree? E.g. how and when does free(p) get called? Is it when return is called? I know it's important not to orphan any nodes, but I don't know how this is avoided here.

Following the debugger and stepping through the code, free(p) clearly isn't called until it seems that a grandparent node is reached - e.g. free_family(p->parents[0]) has been called twice and then the subsequent call to p->parents[0] is NULL, before free(p) frees that stack from the call. I can't get my head around how this works at all.


Apologies for the noob question - I'm new to coding and following CS50x currently.
I won't post the entire code unless required, but each node is defined by the following code. There are 3 generations of these nodes. The last generation of parents receives NULL parent pointers.
typedef struct person
{
    struct person *parents[2];
    char alleles[2];
} person;

My recursive free function is:
// Free `p` and all ancestors of `p`.
void free_family(person *p)
{
    // TODO: Handle base case

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // TODO: Free parents recursively

    free_family(p->parents[0]);
    free_family(p->parents[1]);

    // TODO: Free child

    free(p);
}


It frees from the bottom to the top because it doesn't free the current node until after it has recursed into the two child nodes (which you confusingly call parents). The recursive call does the same thing -- it frees the children before freeing itself. Eventually it reaches the leaves and stops recursing.

Then before each call returns, it frees that level.

Sorry for the confusion. To clarify, I understand they are child nodes but in the problem they are representing biological parents and as such the CS50 distribution code has pre-defined the structs with parent array pointers. Slightly confusing that they point to child nodes which represent parents (and subsequently grandparents). Thank you for the help.

That representation is only semantic within the context of the entire tree. In the context of the call stack at any invocation of your function, parents always refers to the direct parents for the current node pointed to by p. When you make a recursive call, you're just passing one subtree of the current node. And before continuing, that entire subtree (and its subtrees, etc...) is deleted. Upon return from both recursive calls, you now know that your node has deleted its subtrees, and so you can delete the node.

Suggest entering [c] "recursion" "how" is:answer into the search bar above. There are MANY SO examples available. Recursion can be a difficult concept when starting out. Taking the time to study an assortment of different examples may help you find the elusive finger-hold that's right for you, and you can start to gain traction with this data structure concept. Worthwhile!! Good luck...

Aside: Charles Darwin is a well known personage who married his first cousin. Together, this couple had the customary allotment of 4 parents. One generation further "up", though, one finds only 6 -- not 8 -- "grandparents" of the couple. Only mentioning this to introduce to you how "real life data" is a LOT messier than crisp, well-defined, and naive data models. Always be alert to unanticipated complexities arising when coding. Some say "10% of the work solves 90% of the problem, and then 90% of the work solves the last 10% that was not considered at the start of the project." Cheers!

@Fe2O3 - thanks for the tips and that's a great anecdote to learn. Thanks for sharing!

person1
  |- person2
  |    |- person4
  |    |- person5
  |- person3
  |    |- person6
  |    |- person7

Let's assume this is your tree. It's inverted - person1 is the youngest, with parents person2 and person3.
When you go to free person1, your code does the following:
 - Want to free person1, but the parents are to be freed first
 - Try to free person2
    - Try to free person4
        - person4 has no first parent, so no more recursion. Free person4
    - Try to free person5
        - person5 has no second parent, so no more recursion. Free person5
 - Now that yo're done freeing the parents of person2, you actually free person2
 - Repeat above for person3
 - Now that you are done freeing the parents for person1, actually free person1

This is actually fairly simple. What you need to do to understand it is to follow the control flow. Spend some time with the code itself, and try to follow the control flow line-by-line. This isn't async or threaded code, and has a very linear execution sequence. Try not to get lost in the debugger. It's only after you have a good handle on how control flow normally works that you can make effective use of a debugger.
Edit : Additional Notes
There are separate questions here:

How does the program avoid orphaning any nodes?
Why is free() called when it is called?
When does free() actually get called?

As to 1. :
As discussed in another answer, the program avoids orphaning any nodes by freeing the child only after freeing the parents. There is no C magic here, and nothing happening behind the scenes. As the programmer, you have put those commands to execute in that order to create that effect. You would have done so knowing that once you free a child, you lose the references to the child's parents (and by extension, all ancestors), and they can never be freed. Therefore, you make sure to free all of those before you get rid of the references to them.
This brings us to 2. :
free is called, in your code, after the parents are freed.
However, you can just as easily call free() first with no other changes. Then, when you go to free the parents, you'll find nulls. At best, you'll create orphans. At worse, you'll segfault. C itself won't stop you from doing this. There may be IDEs and static code analysis tools that will warn you. The compiler might even warn you. But as C code goes, it's technically valid.
You can avoid this problem while retaining the free-the-child-first sequence by first copying the references to the parents to other variables, then free the child, and then go free the parents. There are (rare) use cases where this kind of approach is needed and used.
This is all entirely upto you to decide how to do it, and to get it right or shoot yourself in the foot.
This brings us, finally, to 3:
free is called when you, the programmer, calls it. You decide when to do this by the order in which the program is written and the various control structures like ifs and fors and function calls you have in place.
Recursive functions are just functions. In other more complex programming languages, recursive functions are just regular functions wearing funny hats. In C, they aren't even doing that. You don't need to tell the compiler that it's recursive. Noone is acting behind the scenes to make sure you don't shoot yourself in the foot. When you call a function, as long as C can find a reference to call with that name (symbol), it will.
There's nothing special about free() either. It's just a function call as well. It could just as easily be do_something_else() instead of free(). Other than the fact that the memory isn't going to get freed (because there's no call to free() in this hypothetical code), it'll behave in exactly the same way.

Thank you for explaining, that’s really useful. So the free(p) is only executed when the function is returned?

free(p) is only executed when that line is reached. That line is only reached after the calls to free the parents because of the way your code is written, which first have to execute fully and return, only after which control flow will move to the next lines. You could call the free() before the calls to free to parents to get different behaviour, but your code will then need to be more complicated.

I suggest you spend some time learning about basic control flow in C. Most programming languages work this way. Statements are executed one after the other, in the order in which they are written, with very specific ways in which the flow can be controlled like loops, conditionals, and function calls. You need to be very familiar with that idea long before you're going to be able to make effective use of a debugger.

This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for explaining, I’m very new to recursion and so it’s a concept that I’m still getting my head around. With regards to understanding control flow, are there any tools to aid? I appreciate the debugger that steps through the code can do this, but you mentioned focusing on control flow - do you mean as a mental exercise? Edit: just saw your more recent comment - I am familiar with control flow but when it comes to recursion I think that adds an extra layer of understanding needed.

Admittedly, that is probably something most of us have learnt in a classroom, or from a text book. It's a very fundamental notion of programming that I couldn't tell you where or when I first learned about it. It's simply something that is. A mental exercise is probably a good start. You can play around with the code with print statements and see how control flows through the program. For simple C, without doing much more complicated things, you can assume that at any point in time there's only one statement executing. A basic programming course may also address this, if any real ones exist.

Recursion is no different from regular functions. Just treat the recursive call as a regular function call. What makes recursion different is that you need to think about things like reentrancy - whether it's safe for multiple copies of the function to execute simultaneously - and how much recursion depth you can handle in terms of memory usage. Neither of these are a concern with your code, and neither effect control flow at all.

It might help if you write down, with your example inputs, the sequence of 'commands' that will be executed. Unwrap and flatten out any branching, turning the program into one long sequence and see what you get. It'll be a tedious exercise, but it'll help you see what's happening. The list I put into my answer is a lazy attempt at that, you can look at it in finer detail.

Thank you very much for your advice. I would argue that there is nothing lazy about your reply and you’ve been abundantly helpful. I was apprehensive about posting such a simple question, but I now have some good direction for my learning. Thank you.

I've added an edit to the answer with some additional thoughts which you might find useful.
